# To compare columns in two tables and update the differences if any

Tags: sql

**Table A**:

```
NAME        ID
---------------
Peter       45
Johny       46
Mary        47
Micheal     48
Elizabeth   49
```

**Table B**:

```
NAME        ID     Gender
-----------------------------
Peter       12       M
Johny       null     M
Mary        47       F
Micheal     48       M
Elizabeth   28       F
```

I want an update query to populate the below result in Table B.

```
NAME        ID     Gender
-----------------------------
Peter       45       M
Johny       46       M
Mary        47       F
Micheal     48       M
Elizabeth   49       F
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: And you've tried what exactly?

Comment: Is Name guaranteed to be unique in either table? ID? At first glance, this structure does not appear to be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Name is unique, here is a starting point depending upon your RDBMS:

```
update b
set b.ID = a.ID
from TableA a
    join TableB b on a.Name = b.Name
where a.ID <> b.ID
    or b.ID is null
```